# Wrong content-type in JSONP calls

Tags: bug, status-completed, api

When passing `jsonp` parameter, the API returns "application/json" instead of "application/javascript".

I found this because if you do:

```
<script src='http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/badges?jsonp=results'></script>
```

On Google Chrome, it doesn't work. You need to add

```
<script src='http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/badges?jsonp=results' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

And even then you get a warning in the console.

Nothing serious but it's not a big change either.

Answer (score 1):

Its odd that no-one complained about this oversight for so long, good catch.

This has been deployed to the API, StackAuth will follow sometime in the near-ish future.

Comment: maybe not a lot of people are using the jsonp variant of the API

Comment: @Pablo: Well, I'm not too sure about that - I'm using it quite a bit.

Comment: @pablo's statement that 'it doesn't work' is incorrect. the content-type may not be correct but chrome handles it just fine, with a warning. both george and i have been leveraging jsonp since day 1 with full browser support.